# Has anyone seen error data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper" undefined using aurelia-cli when deploying to remote server

Tags: syncfusion, aurelia

aurelia-cli 0.31.3

My project runs fine when I just run au run, but when I just build the project and copy the scripts folder and index.html file to my server I do not get any console errors or any other errors but if I inspect  index.html I can see `<script data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper">undefined</script>.`

I have successfully run other projects using aurelia-cli on a remote servers so I am not sure why this one will not run.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

**Update:**
After clearing cache I am now getting errors of unable to load syncfusion-bridge components as seen in this screen show[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, clearing the cached and turning pagespeed off helped me track down the problem.  The ultimate problem is that I was using the only importing the grid component using the bridge in the aurelia.json bundle as seen

```
 {
    "name": "aurelia-syncfusion-bridge",
    "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-syncfusion-bridge/dist/amd",
    "main": "index",
    "resources": [
      "grid/*.js"
    ]
  },
```

changing resources to include all fixed it

```
        "resources": [
          "**/*.js"
        ]
```